# My text won't flow beside my images?

Tags: html, css, image, text

[image: my output]

How do I put the text beside these images? I've tried everything but I can't seem to figure out how? I'd like it to appear BESIDE the image.

jsFiddle using random image: https://jsfiddle.net/0z1pfbs7/

HTML

```
<section class="pdc">
    <div class="moreproduct">
        <div class="bigimg">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="producttext">
            <h3>New Balance</h3>
            <h1>Men's MX608v4</h1>
            <p>SGF</p>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.pdc{
    display: inline;

}
.moreproduct img {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #93a2ad;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.moreproduct ul{
  list-style: none;
}
.moreproduct ul li img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 80px;
}
.bigimg{
    margin-top: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    width: 450px;
    height: 450px;
    margin-left: 240px;
}
.producttext{
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: What is this ***suppposed*** to look like?

Comment: Don't quite understand what you want. What do you mean by "besides"?

Comment: add `display: inline-block` to `.bigimg` inside of your css.

Comment: Also, absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As others already mentioned: Don't use absolute positioning to layout your page.

Note: You need to view the example in full-screen to see that everything is aligned "in one line".

Do you mean something like this:

```css
.pdc{
    display: inline;

}
.moreproduct img {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #93a2ad;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.moreproduct ul{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.moreproduct ul li img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.bigimg{
    margin-top: 2em;
    display: inline-block;
   
    height: 300px;
}
.producttext{
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<section class="pdc">
            <div class="moreproduct">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="bigimg">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="producttext">
                    <h3>New Balance</h3>
                    <h1>Men's MX608v4</h1>
                    <p>SGF</p>

                </div>
            </div>


        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code, you don't need to use position absolute to do this see the code.

```css
.pdc{
    display: inline;
}
.moreproduct img {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #93a2ad;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.moreproduct ul{
  list-style: none;
  float:left;
}
.moreproduct ul li img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.bigimg{
    margin-top: 2em;
    float:left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 450px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.producttext{
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
        <section class="pdc">
            <div class="moreproduct">
                
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                </ul>
              <div class="bigimg">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>

                <div class="producttext">
                    <h3>New Balance</h3>
                    <h1>Men's MX608v4</h1>
                    <p>SGF</p>
                </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>


        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>

.pdc{
    display: inline;

}
.moreproduct img {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #93a2ad;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.moreproduct ul{
  list-style: none;
}
.moreproduct ul li img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 80px;
}
.bigimg{
    margin-top: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    width: 636px;
    height: 450px;
    margin-left: 240px;
    left: 11px;
}
.producttext{

    overflow: hidden;
    float:right;
    padding-top:25%;
}
</style>


<section class="pdc">
    <div class="moreproduct">
        <div class="bigimg">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="producttext">
              <h3>New Balance</h3>
              <h1>Men's MX608v4</h1>
              <p>SGF</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6vUQD.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```